# EF Core Update-Database failing when creating Foreign key

Tags: entity-framework-core

When I run `Update-Database` I get the following error:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
   Failed executing DbCommand (938ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
   ALTER TABLE [port_portal] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_port_portal_port_portal_page_default] FOREIGN KEY ([default_page_id], [organization_id]) REFERENCES [port_portal_page] ([page_id], [organization_id]) ON DELETE NO ACTION;
Failed executing DbCommand (938ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
ALTER TABLE [port_portal] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_port_portal_port_portal_page_default] FOREIGN KEY ([default_page_id], [organization_id]) REFERENCES [port_portal_page] ([page_id], [organization_id]) ON DELETE NO ACTION;
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_port_portal_port_portal_page_default". The conflict occurred in database "ArenaSprint", table "dbo.port_portal_page".
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:8a9a2e38-2f14-4185-818f-919fe99bc5fb
Error Number:547,State:0,Class:16
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_port_portal_port_portal_page_default". The conflict occurred in database "ArenaSprint", table "dbo.port_portal_page".
```

If I run the same script it tries to run in the migration in SSMS directly, it works fine. So why is it failing here? The models and context got reverse engineered from an existing database. When I go into SSMS and generate a `DROP AND CREATE` script for the table that has this foreign key, it comes up with different SQL for that foreign key.

Here is the portion in my DbContext in `OnModelCreate()`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PortPortal>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.PortalId)
            .HasName("PK_orgn_portal");

        entity.HasComment(@"Contains Portal inforamation dministration > Portal List");

        entity.HasIndex(e => e.DefaultPageId)
            .HasName("IX_port_portal");

        entity.Property(e => e.CreatedBy).IsUnicode(false);

        entity.Property(e => e.DateCreated).HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

        entity.Property(e => e.DateModified).HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

        entity.Property(e => e.DefaultDomain)
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("('')")
            .HasComment(@"Field: Default Domain");

        entity.Property(e => e.DefaultPageId).HasComment(@"Field: Default Page ID");

        entity.Property(e => e.FormsAuthentication)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("((1))")
            .HasComment(@"Field: Authentication  ");

        entity.Property(e => e.JqueryInclude).IsUnicode(false);

        entity.Property(e => e.LoginPageId).HasComment(@"Field: Login Page ID");

        entity.Property(e => e.ModifiedBy).IsUnicode(false);

        entity.Property(e => e.NavigationStyleSheet).IsUnicode(false);

        entity.Property(e => e.PortalDesc)
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasComment(@"Field: Portal Description");

        entity.Property(e => e.PortalName)
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasComment(@"Field: Portal Name");

        entity.Property(e => e.PortalNotes)
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasComment(@"Field: Portal Notes");

        entity.Property(e => e.PortalStyleSheet)
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("('')")
            .HasComment(@"Field: Portal Style Sheet");

        entity.Property(e => e.PortalTitle)
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("('')")
            .HasComment(@"Field: Portal Title");

        entity.Property(e => e.TreeStyleSheet).IsUnicode(false);

        entity.HasOne(d => d.Organization)
            .WithMany(p => p.PortPortal)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.OrganizationId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_port_portal_orgn_organization");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.PortPortalPage)
            .WithMany(p => p.PortPortalPortPortalPage)
            .HasForeignKey(d => new { d.DefaultPageId, d.OrganizationId })
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_port_portal_port_portal_page_default");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.PortPortalPageNavigation)
            .WithMany(p => p.PortPortalPortPortalPageNavigation)
            .HasForeignKey(d => new { d.LoginPageId, d.OrganizationId })
            .HasConstraintName("FK_port_portal_port_portal_page_login");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.PortPortalPage1)
            .WithMany(p => p.PortPortalPortPortalPage1)
            .HasForeignKey(d => new { d.PageNotFoundId, d.OrganizationId })
            .HasConstraintName("FK_port_portal_port_portal_page_not_found");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.PortPortalPage2)
            .WithMany(p => p.PortPortalPortPortalPage2)
            .HasForeignKey(d => new { d.PersonPopupPageId, d.OrganizationId })
            .HasConstraintName("FK_port_portal_port_portal_page_popup");

        entity.HasData(new PortPortal
            {
                PortalId = 1,
                CreatedBy = "Setup",
                ModifiedBy = "Setup",
                OrganizationId = 1,
                PortalName = "Staff Web",
                PortalTitle = "My Church Staff Portal",
                PortalDesc = "",
                PortalNotes = "",
                PortalDefLastUpdated = null,
                PortalStyleSheet = "",
                LoginPageId = null,
                DefaultDomain = "",
                FormsAuthentication = true,
                IsMobile = false,
                PageNotFoundId = null,
                PersonPopupPageId = null,
                TreeStyleSheet = null,
                NavigationStyleSheet = null,
                JqueryInclude = null,
                PortalEulaPrompt = true,
                BootstrapCssInclude = null,
                BootstrapJsInclude = null
            });
    });
```

And the migration builder code:

```
migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
    name: "FK_port_portal_port_portal_page_default",
    table: "port_portal",
    columns: new[] { "default_page_id", "organization_id" },
    principalTable: "port_portal_page",
    principalColumns: new[] { "page_id", "organization_id" },
    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
```

UPDATE: I have updated the code block which has the `OnModelCreating()`. Is this the wrong place to seed data?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that at least one of your existing rows in your `port_portal` table already contains a value in one of the two foreign key columns (`default_page_id` or `organization_id`), that does not have a corresponding ID on the principal table (`port_portal_page`).

This would violate the referential integrity of the database and therefore the `ALTER TABLE` statement fails.

Run the following SQL query to find the invalid references:

```sql
select *
from port_portal as pp
left join port_portal_page as ppp on ppp.default_page_id = pp.page_id AND ppp.organization_id = pp.organization_id
where ppp.default_page_id is null;
```

---

> UPDATE: I have updated the code block which has the OnModelCreating(). Is this the wrong place to seed data?

No, the place is generally the right one. Take a look [Data Seeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding), especially the [Limitations of model seed data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#limitations-of-model-seed-data) section.

Where do you apply the migration to the database? Manually outside the application as a script (recommended) or as part of the application code (discouraged)?

If all you seed is that one `PortPortal` entity, than the problem should still be the one that I described above, because you are missing the corresponding entry for the `PortPortalPage` entity and the referential integrity would again be broken.

You can test that by executing a `Sql()` call as part of the `Up()` method with the SQL snippet I suggested above as the base (but inserting the select into a table or something, so you can check it later) and even put a `Debugger.Launch()` call before it to trigger the JIT debugger and then step through the code.

Comment: I can already tell you that that statement will return 0 rows. I'm updating my question with new information, but I think this is happening because I'm seeding data in `OnModelCreating()` ? I didn't include that part before.

Comment: there will be only one entry in port_portal and one in port_portal_page (if the `Update-Database` command were to finish successfully).

Comment: I am familiar with the application doing the migration, but I currently do not have it doing so. I was running the migrations manually via Package Manager console. Is it recommended to seed the data some other way other than using EF Core? I can write scripts to handle this.

Comment: If the data should be part of the migrations, that is usually okay (but see the limitation section I referenced), but might need some manual tweaking (see [Custom initialization logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#custom-initialization-logic)). A simple way to check the order of operations and to trace the issue, is to generate a script of the migrations using [dotnet ef migrations script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-migrations-script) and run it manuall in SSMS, stepping through each line.

Comment: The referential integrity of the data needs to be correct before the `ALTER TABLE` statements runs, which should be not to hard to verify using a generated script.